# Xpath is different in Chrome and Mozilla to identify the same element check box working in Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

Check box has different xpath for Chrome (Version 81.0.4044.138) and Firefox (76.0.1 (64-bit)), It works for one at a time, I am getting following error:

============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-5.4.1, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\eclipse-workspace2\Hybrid-Framework
plugins: allure-pytest-2.8.13
collected 3 items

Testcases\test_login.py sF
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py", line 191, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py", line 247, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in **call**
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in 
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIdi.png).with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\main.py", line 272, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in **call**
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in 
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIdi.png).with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py", line 85, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py", line 100, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\runner.py", line 190, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     hook.pytest_runtest_logreport(report=report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 286, in **call**
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 93, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in 
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIdi.png).with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138\pysrc_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py", line 243, in pytest_runtest_logreport
INTERNALERROR>     exc = _get_error_contents_from_report(report)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner.p2\pool\plugins\org.python.pydev.core_7.5.0.202001101138\pysrc_pydev_runfiles\pydev_runfiles_pytest2.py", line 147, in _get_error_contents_from_report
INTERNALERROR>     report.toterminal(tw)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest\reports.py", line 65, in toterminal
INTERNALERROR>     longrepr.toterminal(out)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest_code\code.py", line 962, in toterminal
INTERNALERROR>     element[0].toterminal(tw)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest_code\code.py", line 992, in toterminal
INTERNALERROR>     entry.toterminal(tw)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest_code\code.py", line 1080, in toterminal
INTERNALERROR>     self._write_entry_lines(tw)
INTERNALERROR>   File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages_pytest_code\code.py", line 1062, in _write_entry_lines
INTERNALERROR>     tw._write_source(source_lines, indents)
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'TerminalWriter' object has no attribute '_write_source'

======================== 1 failed, 1 skipped in 47.12s ========================

XPATH for CHROME:
checkbox_xpath = //*[@id="signupform"]/div/div[6]/div[2]/label/span
XPATH FOR MOZILLA:
checkbox_xpath = //*[@id="signupform"]/div/div[6]/div[2]/label/input

I use OR option and is NOT working

HERE is HTML:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIdi.png)

Comment: Do you seriously expect anyone to attempt to read that?

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath expression are different (note : you forgot the `*` in both) since the first selects a `span` element whereas the second selects an `input` element. But if you look closely, they share the same parent node (`div` element).

It's probably better to click on this div to tick the checkbox :

```
//div[@class="za-tos-container"]
```

Note : If you want further help, please post more details on what you're trying to achieve, a sample of data, and a piece of your code.

Comment: I am trying to go on https://www.zoho.com/ and  then click link  "FreeSignUP" , it will pop up form eith e-mail password and then check box. I have issue to get xpath of check box. for chrome and Fire fox. Same xpath is NOT working for both .

Comment: Following is code:  
from selenium import webdriver
import time
webdriver.driver= None
class Test_Zohoologin():
     BrowserName ="Chrome"
    
    if BrowserName =="Firefox":
        FFox_path = ("C://SEl-Python//Driver//geckodriver.exe")
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FFox_path)
        driver.maximize_window()

    if BrowserName =="Chrome":
        driver= webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://www.zoho.com/")
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/a[6]").click()

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*@id='emailfield']").send_keys("abcdef@gmail.com")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']").send_keys("asdfgh")
    # FOR ====FIREFOX =
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='za-tos-container']/label/input").click()
    
    #==FOR EDGE  #CHROME=
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='za-tos-container']/label/span").click()

Answer (score 0):

use

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='tos']")
```

or

```
 driver.find_element_by_id("tos")
```

and it will work, also when I checked the website it takes some time for the element to load so you will have to use wait put the below imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

and below statement to identify the element and click

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//input[@id='tos']"))).click()
```

Comment: driver.find_element_by_id("tos") is working in Mozilla , but in chrome is giving following Error, I have time .sleep as weel driver wait and until EC condition        selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input tabindex="1" class="za-tos" id="tos" name="tos" value="false" onclick="toggleTosField()" type="checkbox"> is not clickable at point (259, 420). Other element would receive the click: <div class="signup-form">...</div>
E         (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)